# I tried to insert data to SQL using php and html but it didn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql

Whenever I tried to insert data to the table of database it keeps echoing "Connection successful" from connection.php[The connection successful in my insert.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5xZF.png)

insert.php code

```
<?php 
include_once("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['Add'])){
    $productCat = $_POST['category'];

    $insertQuery = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO products_tbl (productCategory) VALUES      (:ucategory)");
    $insertQuery->bindParam(':ucategory',$productCat);
    $insertQuery->execute();
    echo "<script>alert('Successfully Register')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
}
?>
```

connection code

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Ecommercedb";

try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connection success";
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

forms

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<label for="">Product Category</label>
<input type="text" name="category" id="" placeholder="Category">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" name="Add">
</form>
```

I tried removing the echo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA6a3.png)since it wasn't needed but it only lead to

> HTTP:500 error.

I have also checked the connection and it is successful.

I expected there would be an alert saying it is successfully inserted but instead I keep getting the connection success from my connection.php

Comment: remove  `echo "Connection success";` not required at all. and then check.

Comment: if I do I get a HTTP error 500

Comment: Check your server/error logs for details

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the top of your connection.php script. This will help with debugging. There appears to be something very wrong with your data structure if you are adding `productCategory` to your `products_tbl` to build up a list of categories, as opposed to categorising an existing product. You might want to do some reading about [normalization](https://www.google.com/search?q=database+normalization+3nf).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is working as intended, and the issue is likely related to the way you are submitting your form. The "Connection successful" message is being printed because your connection to the database is working, but the form data is not being passed to the insert.php script.

Make sure that you are correctly specifying the action attribute of the form element, and that the method is set to "post". Also, check that the name attributes of the form elements match the names of the variables in the insert.php script.

Additionally, you can try adding some debugging statements to the insert.php script, such as var_dump($_POST) or echo $productCat to check if the values are being passed to the script correctly.

Comment: I did try it out by putting in echo I can see that the form is submitting it correctly however it is not inserting it into the database table. I have checked the naming of the database and the table. However it is still the same

Comment: Its all good now, I restarted my XAMPP and re-inputed everything from scratch and it somehow worked